Collecting questions related to Mt.Gox' insolvency
I am attempting to collect questions that are related to the Mt.Gox insolvency and linking them here.
Please provide any additional suggestions as answers or suggested edits to the question.
Mt.Gox

Why is the disappearance of Mt Gox a problem? 
I have/had 31 bitcoins on MtGox; What are my options now?
Does the Mt Gox attack constitute theft of Bitcoins or just a Denial-of-Service attack?
Huge price difference between Mt.Gox and others. Why?

Transaction Malleability

What is Transaction Malleability?
Is this "transaction malleability" really an issue?
Wouldn't the “malleable transaction” attack be foiled by common sense?

Other sources

Joint statement by other exchanges regarding Mt.Gox
CoinDesk – Mt. Gox Files for Bankruptcy, Claims $63.6m Debt
Falkvinge – The Gox Crater: Crowd Detectives Reveal Billion-Dollar Heist as Inside Job
CoinDesk – Optimism Grows as Mt. Gox Chapter Ends and Bitcoin Turns the Page Especially check out the full time-line at the bottom.

